# Simple proplem contributing to a React Module

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, makefile, package.json

I try to set up my environment to contribute to [react-draggable](https://github.com/mzabriskie/react-draggable/tree/8beb72fb27978bee2879221163dae8d45ade5b8f) React Module.

The developer has a description in his `README.md` but I am stuck at the second step: `npm run dev`. This runs `make dev` like he defined it in the `package.json`.

I get this output in the console:

```
PS D:\Projekte\module_dev\react-draggable> npm run dev

> react-draggable@3.0.5 dev D:\Projekte\module_dev\react-draggable
> make dev

make i info Invoking dev target
(node:1740) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: undefined
(node:1740) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:1740) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
make × ERR  not found: make-$(BIN)
```

I did also try the following commands:

- ***npm install make -g*** to install make
- ***npm install --only=dev*** to install the packages defined in `devDependencies` in pakage.json

I work in a Windows 10 environment.

To me it looks like make can not resolve BIN defined in the Makefile:

```
export BIN := $(shell npm bin)
```

Do you have an idea how I can proceed on this one? It would be a great help for me. Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like the build instructions need to be fixed.  In the event that there is a flaw, it could help to report this issue at that GitHub repository.  https://github.com/mzabriskie/react-draggable/issues  Your extra advice to `npm install make -g` would already make a worthwhile contribution to their readme.

Comment: Thank you @Wyck. Done: https://github.com/mzabriskie/react-draggable/issues/365

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about it, I came to the conclusion that he was using "make" from Linux and not the make node module.

So I tried it on an Ubuntu VM but that fails too. At least it was able to resolve the BIN variable. I understand that it is easier for the developer to manage his code with such tools, but for me it is not easy to understand.

Here is the error:

```
osboxes@osboxes:~/dev/react-draggable$ npm run dev

> react-draggable@3.0.5 dev /home/osboxes/dev/react-draggable
> make dev

make: *** No rule to make target '/home/osboxes/dev/react-draggable/node_modules/.bin', needed by 'dev'.  Stop.

npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-29-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "dev"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! react-draggable@3.0.5 dev: `make dev`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the react-draggable@3.0.5 dev script 'make dev'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the react-draggable package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     make dev
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs react-draggable
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls react-draggable
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
```